How to get rid of jna tmp can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software in Sourcetree?
Whenever I commit/push using SourceTree, I get the following popup.
It looks like SoucreTree is creating some executables on the fly.
Jna can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. Sourcetree downloaded this file today at 10:38


How can I get rid of it?

In General, JNA needs its OS-specific native library to execute properly.  The .tmp file you see is a result of the Native class being loaded, looking for this library in predefined locations, and if not found, extracting it to a temp file.   You can pre-extract that native library and have it in a location you define with the "jna.library.path" system property.  Specifically to SourceTree it seems you have a commit hook.  You may need to edit that hook to define the system property as specified.

It turns out that installing command line tools for SourceTree helped.
